# How can I listen for and report server (SSH) connections via a Python script?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, python-2.7

I am a bit new to Python, but an experienced programmer. I am writing a Python 2.7 script which should be started by a Linux server at boot. The purpose is to send, via various mediums, notification(s) when a user connects to the server.

My problem has to do with the actual listening. How can I make the module see when a user connects (via SSH, or whatever) to the server? Some quick pseudocode:

```
# When a connection is made
    # Send an email
    # Send a text message
    # Send notification to server output
    # Etc...
```

*I'd like to include some details in the notification, like username, IP, connection time, last connection, a cute custom connection message, whatever. Any protips on how to do those things best is appreciated as well, but I'm sure I can figure this out elsewhere.*

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: If your goal is notification (python optional), something like this might be a faster solution: http://www.tiger-computing.co.uk/get_notified_with_every_ssh_login

Comment: I'd probably do that by watching the server's log file. You get most of that info in the logs by default.

Comment: Do you actually want SSH to work or do you just want to notify about a TCP connection to port 22?

Comment: @NiklasB. Not sure what you're asking. I just need to know when a connection to the server happens, and I need to be able to obtain details about the connection/user.

Comment: @Lief: Your comment to the answer also answered that question. Thanks.

Comment: @miku I have looked at that, and appreciate the link :) I'm just looking for a way to do everything in Python. My motivation is clarity, practice, and expandability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your sshd is using syslog, you could configure syslog to send the auth facility to a named pipe, then write a Python script to read the FIFO. [Here's](http://www.johnandcailin.com/blog/john/how-setup-real-time-email-notification-critical-syslog-events) an example that uses bash.

Or, like sblom said, you could tail /var/log/auth.log in a Python script. Either way, you should get lines like this:

```
Mar 29 19:58:13 mybox sshd[13914]: Accepted password for jtg from 192.168.0.20 port 51538 ssh2
```

Answer (score 2):

[pam_python](http://ace-host.stuart.id.au/russell/files/pam_python/) will allow you to write a PAM module that can notify of authentication attempts on any service that uses PAM.

Comment: My server uses OpenSSH, and I'm looking at some tuts about PAM and OpenSSH, but I am unfortunately completely unfamiliar with the technology. :/